# WebConfiguration Manager write example

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have this code that can read the connectionString in the web.config but I cannot find an example of how to update them.

```
// Show how to use OpenWebConfiguration(string).
// It gets he appSettings section of a Web application 
// runnig on the local server. 
static void OpenWebConfiguration1()
{
     // Get the configuration object for a Web application
     // running on the local server. 
     System.Configuration.Configuration config =
        WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/configTest") 
        as System.Configuration.Configuration; 

     // Get the appSettings.
     KeyValueConfigurationCollection appSettings =
         config.AppSettings.Settings;


     // Loop through the collection and
     // display the appSettings key, value pairs.
     Console.WriteLine("[appSettings for app at: {0}]", "/configTest");
     foreach (string key in appSettings.AllKeys)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} Value: {1}",
         key, appSettings[key].Value);
      }

      Console.WriteLine();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        // for update existing value  
        appSettings["ExistingKey"].Value = "updated value";


        // for add new key value
        appSettings.Add("NewKey", "new value");

        // for save
        config.Save();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string temp = "Data Source=" + tbServerName.Text + ";";
        temp += "Initial Catalog=" + tbDatabaseName.Text + ";";
        temp += "Persist Security Info=True;";
        temp += "User ID=" + tbUserId.Text + ";";
        temp += "Password=" + tbPassword.Text;
        var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");
        section.ConnectionStrings["iFishConnectionString"].ConnectionString = temp;
        configuration.Save();
```